# Is "Select * from table 1,table 2 a valid query?

Tags: sql

Sql query is valid or not.
i have been asked this in an interview?

Comment: Wait, are you in the interview right now, or was this earlier and you want to follow up on the correct answer?

Comment: See [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the query you write is *not* a valid query:

```
Select *
from table 1, table 2
```

Numbers are not allowed as table aliases.  In many databases, you can do:

```
select *
from table "1", table "2"
```

If you want numeric aliases.

If you didn't intend the space before "1" and "2", the query is equivalent to:

```
select *
from table1 cross join table2
```

Perfectly valid, but the `cross join` syntax is much preferable.

Answer (score 5):

This is a valid query - it produces a cartesian product of the two tables. It is equivalent to this query in the ANSI SQL syntax:

```
select *
from table1
join table2 on 1=1
```

The usefulness of this query is highly debatable, though.

Here is a [demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b7c6/1).

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what database you are using.

It has been valid SQL for a long time, but some recent versions of SQL Server for example is dropping the syntax in favor of using the `join` keyword.